# In ddd practice,Are the CRUD methods should be put in the Model Objects

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, crud

I am trying to practice domain driven design,the basic structure of the code includes the following objects:

```
Action->Facade->
Service
Model
Repository
```

Where do you think the CRUD methods should be put in the Model just like the following:

```
order.save(new order())
```

Or be put in the facade just like the following:

```
addOrderFacade.save(new order())
```

Comment: What do you mean "CRUD methods" ? Methods that persist to/rehydrate entities from a persistent storage ? => Repository. Methods that operate CRUD use cases ? => Controller or Application Service. Methods that update entities as a result of a CRUD operation => Domain layer. CRUD operations don't happen in just 1 method of 1 layer, they span across several layers...

Answer (score 7):

A 'save' or 'delete' method, belongs to the repository. Usually Save is called by a Service or a command handler (if you're using a command based approach to update the domain). Save handles CU from CRUD, D gets its own method , the R part is the interesting one.

WHen R means 'GetEntity' in order to update it, then it can be part of the domain repository (there is more than 1 repository) handled in the same place as the Save.

However if you want to Read to display, basicaly just queries which returns results to a user, then a different repository dedicated to queries, as well as a simplified read only model should be used. This repo can be called from the controller or even the UI.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to put them in domain class because,

Your domain class package could be reused somewhere in other app where your DAO layer would be different, So it is better to create another layer over models for DAO

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to put CRUD- methods in the repository or service layer rather than in the model. Indeed, when using frameworks like Spring or Hibernate you are enticed to use this approach. For that reason alone it is usually easier:

- other developers expect it
- frameworks support it
- tutorials and examples assume it

However from a design perspective there is a strong case to be made against this approach. It leads to an [anemic domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model), in other words objects with only state and no behavior (structs) which in all fairness is not very object-oriented. A lot of data passing is needed through view, controller, service and repository layers and a lot of 'overhead' code is required to bring state and behavior together. The lack of attention to a canonical model layer might also lead to mismatching, fragmented models between teams.

An approach that tries to avoid this design pitfall is often called [domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), defined as such by Eric Evans. Note that within DDD there is still a place for services and repositories, from the Wikipedia page:

- Service: When an operation does not conceptually belong to any object. Following the natural contours of the problem, you can implement these operations in services. The Service concept is called "Pure Fabrication" in GRASP.
- Repository: methods for retrieving domain objects should delegate to a specialized Repository object such that alternative storage implementations may be easily interchanged.
- Factory: methods for creating domain objects should delegate to a specialized Factory object such that alternative implementations may be easily interchanged.

If you are interested, check out the [software tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Software_tools_to_support_domain-driven_design) that support DDD and (just below) the DDD sample applications.

Comment: I'm not sure about the correlation here. No CRUD methods in a domain object doesn't necessarily mean that it's anemic. You've got plenty of other types of behaviors besides CRUD.

Also, I agree that part of a Create operation for an entity can take place in that Entity's Aggregate Root. But you will certainly not put in an Aggregate Root methods that add entities directly to a persistent store. This is a job for a Repository.

Comment: There are arguments for and against as I indicated at the start of my answer. The location of CRUD methods is not the whole issue here IMO. We need to decide how we are going to divide responsabilities and there is a clear rift between framework convention (instigated by Java Beans) and open-minded Object Orientation.